# Google blocks map API, GWT shows severity high, will this cause SEO problems?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, web-crawlers, googlebot

Google blocked map API, GWT showed **severity** high.

[image]

What is the effect on SEO?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you are using the Static Maps API or if you are doing direct tile access. Direct tile access is prohibited by Google, so they will block you if the server suspects you're pulling down tiles for caching. And that's bad for SEO.

Comment: I will check this out.